# Visual c++ thread with mutex not blocking

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2005, waitforsingleobject

I'm developing with VC2005, and I'm having a problem with a thread.

I have a thread that dequeue data from a queue and send it. But this thread send one petition and have to wait for the answer to send a new petition (I want to put a timeout to prevent a infinite timeout).

I have a thread like this:

```
while (true){
    dequeue()
    send()
    WaitForSingleObject(ptClass->getMutex(),10000);
}
```

But this WaitForSingleObject never stops... I've init event like this:

```
    HANDLE ghMutex = CreateEvent(NULL,FALSE, FALSE, "");
```

The idea is to block the thread to stop sending data, and when the answer comes, unblock this thread to send a new petition... Why never stops???

regards

Comment: That's not a mutex. That's an event.  I think you need to show more code.

Comment: It probably is stopping but only for 10 secs. Then it'll send the next packet, since you provided a timeout.

Answer (score 1):

This thread you have is waiting for the event to be SET to signaled so it can be woken up again.  You have to set the event to signalled using [SetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Not sure where you'd do it, as I don't know your architecture, but that's what's missing.

The WaitForSingleObject is taking your thread out of CPU context, but it isn't being woken up again.

Your timeout of your Wait should be set to INFINITE if you want it to wait until the event has been set to signaled and you cannot guarantee that it will happen immediately.

You're not using a mutex, you're using a AutoResetEvent, but you have to set it!

Comment: he's rather asking why does it never block, instead of why does it block indefinitely, if i understood it correctly.